# ASP.NET Core MVC : page does not render the hrefs

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am experiencing a problem with a page in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app. Please see the screenshot attached for the page structure in the folder.

When I first land on the dashboard page, the hrefs are generated. The minute I click on either the "Patients" or the "Add a new patients" page, the rest of the hrefs aren't generated, but this doesn't happen when I click on "Create New Admin" and "Change Email" links.

I would appreciate that if you could help me out with this problem. many thanks.

```
 <a class="nav-link " href="/identity/account/manage/index">Dashboard</a>    
 <a class="nav-link" href="/identity/account/manage/register">Create New Admin</a>    
 <a class="nav-link" href="/identity/account/manage/email">Change Email</a>     
 <a class="nav-link " href="/identity/account/manage/patients">Patients</a>    
 <a class="nav-link " href="/identity/account/manage/patients/create">Add a new patients</a>
```

Comment: [Folder Structure][1]
[Links generated][2]
[Links not appearing][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuzHd.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23etK.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glBrj.jpg

Comment: here are the screenshots
[Folder Structure][1]
[Links generated][2]
[Links not appearing][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuzHd.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23etK.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glBrj.jpg

Comment: This is not how MVC works in ASP NET Web. It doesn't work with folders structure. It works with controllers and methods.

Comment: It should be like this format `<a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ControllerActionName_Or_MethodName"> Dashboard</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anchor Tag Helper attributes, like this：

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Test1()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Test/patients.cshtml");
        }
```

View:

```
<a asp-controller="test"
   asp-action="test1">Add a new patients</a>
```

Result:

[image]

For more related usage, please refer to this document：

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Razor Pages functionality (which I think you are based on the screenshots), you need to generate the URLs by using the UrlHelper.

Try the following:

```
 <a class="nav-link " href="@Url.Page("/identity/account/manage/patients")">Patients</a>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio